# Install mupdf-plugin/backend for `zathura` document viewer

Tags: software-installation, pdf, mupdf

I like the speed of `MuPDF` and the ui of `Zathura`

Luckily there is a [mupdf-backend for Zathura](https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/plugins/).

Unfortunately it is not in the repositories and building following the [instructions](https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura-pdf-mupdf/) failed on an error:

```
Makefile:25: *** "The minimum required version of zathura is 0.2.0".
```

While the version that I have installed is `zathura 0.3.5`

How do I install the plugin in Ubuntu (16.04)?

Comment: Did you manage do build it?

Comment: No, it failed on above error

Answer (score 4):

> While the version that I have installed is zathura 0.3.5

This is the version of your zathura pdf viewer; the error message is for the development files for zathura plugins, which you can get by installing the package `zathura-dev`.

---

> How do I install the plugin in Ubuntu (16.04)?

Here's a procedure to compile the plugin on Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04.

First, you need to compile `libmupdf-dev` version 1.11.

Clone the repo of the project:

```
$ git clone --recursive git://git.ghostscript.com/mupdf.git
```

Enter its root directory:

```
$ cd mupdf
```

Checkout the branch tagged `1.11-rc1`:

```
$ git checkout 1.11-rc1
```

Update the third party libraries:

```
$ git submodule update --init
```

Install some necessary dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxcursor-dev libxi-dev libxinerama-dev libxrandr-dev mesa-common-dev pkg-config
```

Compile `libmupdf-dev`:

```
$ CFLAGS=-fPIC make HAVE_X11=no HAVE_GLUT=no prefix=/usr/local
  ├──────────┘
  └ pass some flags to `$ gcc`, otherwise the compilation of `zathura-pdf-mupdf` will fail,
    with an error  message recommending you to recompile with those flags.
```

Install `checkinstall` to install the files as a deb package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

Use it to install the files under the package `libmupdf-dev`:

```
$ sudo checkinstall -y --pkgversion=1.11 --pkgname=libmupdf-dev
```

Now you can compile the zathura plugin.
Get out of the `mupdf/` directory and clone the repo of `zathura-pdf-mupdf`:

```
$ cd ..
$ git clone https://git.pwmt.org/pwmt/zathura-pdf-mupdf.git
```

Enter its root directory:

```
$ cd zathura-pdf-mupdf
```

Checkout the branch 0.3.1:

```
$ git checkout 0.3.1
```

Install some necessary dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libjbig2dec0-dev libjpeg-dev libopenjp2-7-dev libssl-dev zathura-dev
```

Finally, compile and install:

```
$ sudo make install
```

---

It seems that you can't easily go beyond the versions 1.11 and 0.3.1 for `libmupdf-dev` and `zathura-pdf-mupdf`, on Ubuntu 16.04. But on Ubuntu 18.04, you can go a little higher if you want:

```
┌───────┬──────────────┬───────────────────┐
│       │ libmupdf-dev │ zathura-pdf-mupdf │
├───────┼──────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ 16.04 │     1.11     │       0.3.1       │
├───────┼──────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ 18.04 │     1.13     │       0.3.2       │
└───────┴──────────────┴───────────────────┘
```

Which gives:

```
$ git clone --recursive git://git.ghostscript.com/mupdf.git
$ cd mupdf
$ git checkout 1.13.0-rc1
$ git submodule update --init
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxcursor-dev libxi-dev libxinerama-dev libxrandr-dev mesa-common-dev pkg-config
$ CFLAGS=-fPIC make HAVE_X11=no HAVE_GLUT=no prefix=/usr/local
$ sudo apt-get install checkinstall
$ sudo checkinstall -y --pkgversion=1.13 --pkgname=libmupdf-dev

$ cd ..
$ git clone https://git.pwmt.org/pwmt/zathura-pdf-mupdf.git
$ cd zathura-pdf-mupdf
$ git checkout 0.3.2
$ sudo apt-get install libjbig2dec0-dev libjpeg-dev libopenjp2-7-dev libssl-dev zathura-dev
$ sudo make install
```

---

If you want to remove the plugin, run:

```
$ sudo make uninstall
```

It will remove the `/usr/lib/zathura/pdf.so` from `zathura-pdf-poppler`, so reinstall the latter:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall zathura-pdf-poppler
```

---

Once the plugin is installed, you may need to make zathura the default program to open a pdf (and an epub); so run:

```
$ xdg-mime default zathura-pdf-mupdf.desktop application/pdf application/epub+zip
```

---

If the compilation of `libmupdf-dev` fails because of a missing file, try to find the package to which it belongs with `$ apt-file search <file>`, or read `docs/building.html`, header “Compiling on Linux” (if the file doesn't exist, temporarily switch to master `$ git checkout master`).

And maybe try to apply some debian patches before compiling:

```
$ git clone https://salsa.debian.org/koster/mupdf
$ ls mupdf/debian/patches
0001-mupdf_manpage.patch
0003-Sort-files-in-static-library-to-make-the-build-repro.patch
0003-use-debian-flavor-build-options.patch
0004-MuPDF-crossbuild-use-target-arch-pkg-config.patch
0005-MuPDF-crossbuild-use-host-cc-for-utils.patch
0006-Allow-disabling-objcopy.patch
0007-typographical-and-formatting-fixes-to-the-manual.patch
0008-PATCH-Fix-700043-Don-t-assume-a-font-is-t3-just-beca.patch
0009-PATCH-Bug-700442-Add-a-recursion-depth-check-to-prev.patch
0010-PATCH-Throw-when-page-number-is-out-of-range.patch
0011-Avoid-being-smart-about-keeping-only-a-single-refere.patch
0012-Fix-text-used-as-clip-mask-in-pdfwrite-device.patch
0013-Fix-typo-in-pdf-write-device.patch
series
```

Apply the ones you consider the most useful, by running this command while in the directory of the targeted file:

```
$ patch -b </path/to/patch
```

The `-b` option passed to `$ patch` creates a backup of a file before patching it. The backup file bears the extension `.orig`.

If you want to reverse the effect of a patch, use the `-R` option.

```
$ patch -R </path/to/patch
        ^^
```

And use `--dry-run` to simulate a patching.

Comment: Thx, for your  excellent instructions. Do you happen to know why it's missing in the repo's or how do we get zathura-pdf-mupdf included in repositories?

Comment: @Janghou No sorry, I don't know why it's not in the repo. In case you're interested, the [chapter 15](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/debian-packaging.html) of the Debian Administrator's Handbook explains how to create a Debian Package, how to create a package repository for APT, and how to become a package maintainer. There's also the [issue tracker](https://git.pwmt.org/pwmt/zathura-pdf-mupdf/issues) of zathura-pdf-mupdf where you could ask a debian package as a feature request.

Comment: Following your instructions for Ubuntu 18.10 verbatim in Ubuntu 19.10, I get this error at the very last step (`sudo make install` in the `zathura-pdf-mupdf`) directory: `index.c:73:13: error: ‘zathura_link_target_t’ {aka ‘struct zathura_link_target_s’} has no member named ‘scale’`. What should I do differently in 19.10?

Comment: I don't have Ubuntu 19.10, so I can't make any tests.  A google search gave me [this link](https://github.com/facebook/zstd/issues/1872#issuecomment-562189672) which suggests to include `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE` or `-D_BSD_SOURCE` in the cflags: `$ CFLAGS=-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE make && sudo make install`.  I have no idea whether it will fix your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither option helped. But I've found [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~spvkgn/+archive/ubuntu/zathura-mupdf) at launchpad, which seems to be by one of the plugin developers. I've installed it and the plugin is now listed in `zathura --version`. Yet, I can't see its benefits. Say, I have a large PDF file. In standard (poppler) Zathura it took quite some time to search a phrase in this file. And in standard MuPDF search worked almost instantly on the same file. After I've installed zathura-pdf-mupdf, the search in Zathura is still slow, as with poppler. Any hints?

Answer (score 3):

The plugin is still not included in Debian repos and so I decided to package it myself.

I've uploaded `zathura-pdf-mupdf` package to Launchpad PPA [ppa:spvkgn/zathura-mupdf](https://launchpad.net/~spvkgn/+archive/ubuntu/zathura-mupdf), it contains packages for 16.04, 16.10, 17.04 and 17.10 Ubuntu series. The plugin compiled against library from latest `MuPDF` 1.11 version.

Please feel free to let me know if any issues with this package occurs.

Comment: Any chance to see this on 18.04?

Comment: hi! how did you do it for debian?

Answer (score 2):

A dirty and hacky way is to use the **Arch** binary.

[Download](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/zathura-pdf-mupdf/) and extract the binary `/usr/lib/zathura/pdf.so` from the package and copy it to e.g. `/usr/lib/zathura/pdf.so` on your Ubuntu machine. Better rename your existing pdf.so (poppler) to pdf.bu so it won't conflict.

The plugin is recognized:

```
$ zathura --version
zathura 0.3.5
(plugin) djvu (0.2.5) (/usr/lib/zathura/djvu.so)
(plugin) pdf-mupdf (0.3.0) (/usr/lib/zathura/pdf.so)
(plugin) ps (0.2.3) (/usr/lib/zathura/ps.so)
(plugin) cb (0.1.5) (/usr/lib/zathura/cb.so)
```

Till now I haven't seem much stability issues. Zathura is much faster then before, especially in rendering (huge images) and searching.

Be aware, in general it is not recommended to `install` software this way. It is a binary from a different distribution, it will not be updated nor patched automatically. Use it at your own risk.

Advantage is that the `zathura-pdf-mupdf-0.3.0` plugin also supports the `epub` format.

Hopefully the plugin will be included in the Ubuntu repositories in the near future.

Comment: Arch's `zathura-pdf-mupdf` is now [here](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/zathura-pdf-mupdf/).  (Haven't tried it yet.  Ubuntu still doesn't have this on the verge of 2024??)

Comment: So I tried this method, but I get an error when I run `zathura --version`: "error: Could not load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zathura/libpdf-mupdf.so' (libmupdf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)."  If I try to open a file, I just get a blank page.  Renaming libpdf-mupdf.so to libmupdf.so doesn't help.  It might be similar to what is reported [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=258772).